# Django App works fine locally but fails on Heroku

Tags: django, heroku

I am trying to deploy this app https://bitbucket.org/hybird/creme_crm-1.2 on Heroku.
I followed the guide https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django
The app works fine on the local server using django dev server or gunicorn with "foreman start" but fails on Heroku with this error:

```
[INFO] Starting gunicorn 0.14.6
Starting gunicorn 0.14.6
[INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:16635 (2)
Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:16635 (2)
[INFO] Using worker: sync
Using worker: sync
[INFO] Booting worker with pid: 5
Booting worker with pid: 5
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py", line 79, in _wrapped_view_func
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/views.py", line 69, in login
    context_instance=RequestContext(request, current_app=current_app))
  File "/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/context.py", line 172, in __init__
    for processor in get_standard_processors() + processors:
  File "/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/context.py", line 150, in get_standard_processors
    raise ImproperlyConfigured('Error importing request processor module %s: "%s"' % (module, e))
ImproperlyConfigured: Error importing request processor module creme_core.context_processors: "No module named creme"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was pushing to heroku from inside the application folder.
Suppose my application is in the folder creme. I must create a folder containing the creme folder, requirements.txt and Procfile. The error was that I put requirements and Procfile inside the creme folder, it works on localhost but not on Heroku.

Answer (score 0):

The error says you are missing a module : creme_core

When you deploy a project to heroku, heroku uses a pip freeze requirements file which contains all of the modules in your project. Heroku downloads all the modules in the requirements file while deploying your application.

Make sure you have a requirments.txt file (pip freeze file) : it's in the documentation under pip freeze [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django#deploy-to-heroku)

Comment: I have a requirements.txt file, but creme_core is already on the source code that I pushed to Heroku, it is part of the web app. As I said the app works fine on localhost.

Comment: After some research it looks like its an error not related to your requirements. It's more of some local vars misconfiguration. Specifically it looks like something that has to do with your context processor var that is located in your settings file